# Error al pasar un string desde una barra de navegación en Android a otra activity

Tags: android

Estoy tratando de pasar una variable string de una activity a otra activity sin éxito, estos son mis datos:

Dentro de Activity1 tengo este String: stringInfoUSB y este intent

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
.
.
final UsbDevice device = driver.getDevice();
final String stringInfoUSB = String.format("Driver: %s  Vendor: %s Product: %s",driver.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                HexDump.toHexString((short) device.getVendorId()),
                HexDump.toHexString((short) device.getProductId()));
.
.
.
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_usb) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, UsbInfoActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("infoUSB", stringInfoUSB);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Este es la actividad2 que recibe la variable:

```
public class UsbInfoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button mBotonCancel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_usb_info );

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();                        
    String textoImportado1=bundle.getString("Info_USB");

    mBotonCancel = (Button)findViewById( R.id.bt2_SendButton ) ;

    String bufferTexto2 = textoImportado1;
    TextView mDumpTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2_ReadValues);
    mDumpTextView.setText(bufferTexto2);

    mBotonCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent2, 0);
        }
    });

}
```

necesito enviar este string a la activity2 llamada UsbInfoActivity, despues de seleccionar un item de una barra de navegación, pero stringinfoUSB me da ERROR!, alguien me podria decir cual error?

Comment: Donde te da el error? al hacer el putExtra o en la otra clase? y un poco mas especifico con el error por favor

Comment: Me da error al hacer putExtra, el compilador me dice que no reconoce la variable  stringInfoUSB

Comment: Podrias mostrar el codigo del UsbInfoActivity, seguro no estas obteniendo el string debidamente :D

Comment: @W1ll declara únicamente la variable  private String stringInfoUSB ; y la evaluas en el método onNavigationItemSelected() o en onCreate().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeramente tienes un error al enviar el texto, estas escribiendo incorrectamente la llave:

```
 intent.putExtra("infoUSB", stringInfoUSB);
```

y lo tratas de recibir

```
String textoImportado1=bundle.getString("Info_USB");
```

debes recibirlo con la misma key que lo envías:

```
String textoImportado1=bundle.getString("info_USB");
```

---

Segundo, te recomiendo definir las variables, pero evaluar en `onCreate()` o en este caso en `onNavigationItemSelected()` sus valores:

```
private UsbDevice device;
private String stringInfoUSB;
...
...  
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    device = driver.getDevice();
    stringInfoUSB = String.format("Driver: %s  Vendor: %s Product: %s",driver.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                HexDump.toHexString((short) device.getVendorId()),
                HexDump.toHexString((short) device.getProductId()));

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_usb) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, UsbInfoActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("infoUSB", stringInfoUSB);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El detalle esta en que la variable que intentas enviar "infoUSB" no es la misma a la que intentas recuperar "Info_USB", ambas deben ser la misma variable en tu primer Activity tienes intent.putExtra(**"infoUSB"**, stringInfoUSB); por lo tanto en tu segundo Activity debe ser la misma String textoImportado1=bundle.getString(**"infoUSB"**);